# How can I perform this result table by mysql from my input table

Tags: mysql

I have this input table:

[image]

With which MySQL statement can I create such an output table?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is there any logic behind this splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Split comma separated string into rows concatenate square brackets (`[]`) around your string to make it into a JSON array. Then use `JSON_TABLE` to convert it into a table :

We need to create two CTEs one for IDs and then other for KEYs the join them together to get the expected output :

```
with cte_id_list as ( 
   select ID_LIST, j.ID, row_number() over (partition by ID_LIST) as rn
   from mytable t
   cross join JSON_TABLE(
                       CONCAT('["', REPLACE(t.ID_LIST, ';', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' 
                       COLUMNS (
                       ID int PATH '$'
                      ) 
                    ) j
),
cte_key_list as (
   select ID_LIST, j.`KEY`, row_number() over (partition by ID_LIST) as rn
   from mytable t
   cross join JSON_TABLE(
                       CONCAT('["', REPLACE(t.Mykey_LIST, ';', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' 
                       COLUMNS (
                       `KEY` text PATH '$'
                      ) 
                    ) j
)
select ci.ID, concat('D', dense_rank() over (order by ci.ID_LIST)) as DUB, ck.`KEY`
from cte_id_list ci
inner join cte_key_list ck on ck.ID_LIST = ci.ID_LIST and ci.rn = ck.rn
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/g9eE_Ul7)

Comment: GREAT & sophisticated! thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query

```
SELECT
  ID,
  CONCAT('D', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID_LIST)) AS DUB,
  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Mykey_LIST, ';', n.digit+1), ';', -1)) AS KEY
FROM
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID_LIST, ';', n.digit+1) AS ID,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(Mykey_LIST, ';', n.digit+1) AS Mykey_LIST
    FROM
      (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
    CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT @row_number:=0) r
    JOIN
      (SELECT @row_number:=@row_number+1 AS row_number, ID_LIST, Mykey_LIST
      FROM your_table
      ORDER BY ID_LIST) t
    ON
      n.digit+1 <= LENGTH(ID_LIST) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ID_LIST, ';', '')) + 1
  ) t
ON
  t.ID != ''
ORDER BY
  ID;
```